# How can I use a variable which is declared inside my servlet in the JSP page?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have declared an `int` variable in my servlet.

How can I use it in the JSP page?

Answer (score 4):

Set it as a request attribute before forwarding the request to the JSP.

```
int someInt = 42;
request.setAttribute("someInt", someInt);
request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/some.jsp").forward(request, response);
```

Then you can access it the usual way by EL in JSP:

```html
<p>Some int is ${someInt}.</p>
```

This is rather basic though. I'd suggest to invest some time in going through the proper books/tutorials.

#### See also:

- [Our Servlets wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/servlets/info)
- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)